# Changing order of comment section in CSV file using univocity

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I am using univocity CSV parser to export my contents to CSV file.
Here is my expected CSV file output,

```
#Comment Section-1
#Comment Section-2
Header-1,Header2,Header3
Data-1,data-2,data-3
```

But while exporting the contents to CSV file i am getting below format,

```
Header-1,Header2,Header3
#Comment Section-1
#Comment Section-2
Data-1,data-2,data-3
```

How do i move the comment section to top in univocity CSV parser lib ?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    //let's write to a String to make this easy to test
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();

    CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings();
    //set headers
    settings.setHeaders("a", "b", "c");
    //automatically write headers when the first data row is written
    settings.setHeaderWritingEnabled(true);

    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(out, settings);
    //write comment
    writer.commentRow("lalala");

    //write data rows
    writer.writeRow("1", "3", "6");
    writer.writeRow("3", "1", "1");

    writer.close();

    //print output
    System.out.println(out);
```

The output produced is:

```
#lalala
a,b,c
1,3,6
3,1,1
```

Hope this helps.